# Regular Expression to check a string with special characters

Tags: c#, regex

I need to check whether my string got only

alphabets of the form

- Text

or of the form
 - 'Text'

or of the form
 - "Text"

How to frame a regex for that? Currently what im using is provided below and that seems not working. Please help me modify this. Thanks in advance.

```
      Regex isString = new Regex("[^a-zA-Z]|[^']|[^\"]");
```

Comment: your requirement is not clear. Can you describe more? Your current regx will match with any thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Regex isString = new Regex("^['][a-zA-Z]*[']|[\"][a-zA-Z]*[\"]|[a-zA-Z]*$");
```

Comment: But Sir, i dont want a string with 'text".

Comment: @NewBie - Try the above, if the backreference solution isn't working for you.

Answer (score 2):

```
Regex isString = new Regex("(['\"]?)[a-zA-Z]+\\1$");
```

this will match `"text"`, `'text'` and not with `'text"`

Comment: but i dont want a string with 'text". This should return false.

Comment: What's that 1 representing in the regex?

Comment: it is a back reference. It referring to the matched string in first parenthesis (first group ).That is why it is not going to match with 'text".  See this http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html.

Comment: ah then use this  (['\"]?)[a-zA-Z]+\\1$